# Android App to read data over USB

Tags: arduino

I am designing a temperature sensor which I could read the data send over USB to a Android app.

I am using Arduino Uno and a temperature sensor and I have this setup working as I can read temperature by a serial terminal on a PC, but I want the Android app to receive the readings from the Arduino. I used a Sparkfun USB Host shield but the Android with 4.0.1 cannot find the USB device.

Am I using the wrong board? Maybe I should use a Arduino ADK to get it working?

Has anyone any success with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

[Android USB Host + Arduino: How to communicate without rooting your Android Tablet or Phone](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=549)